# Possible to use SASS in atom editor?

Tags: sass, atom-editor

I've been using the atom editor for ~2 weeks and I like how easily expandable it is.  I don't like that styling is in LESS, but since the premise of the project is that modules can be shifted around for customization, I thought it would not be hard to change this to SASS.

However I've not found a way to do this.  I won't ask if it's possible - everything is 'possible' - is it possible without ripping atom apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible without going in and rewriting bits of Atom, specifically the `ThemeManager` and perhaps writing a replacement for the `LessCompileCache` class. There is currently no plugin interface or API for stylesheet compilation.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so it's possible, but would take some work.  good to know!